# How to complete rxjs Subject when the webpage is reload/refresh

Tags: typescript

I am providing the js library. The library provide class can be initiated and the class has the rxjs Subject.

```
export class A {
   private aSubject;

   constructor() {
       this.aSubject = new Subject();
   }

   public dispose() {
       this.aSubject.complete();
   }
}
```

Any one using the above js library class

```
const a = new A();
a.dispose();
```

But I would like to know that when the webpage is reload or refresh and caller not call dispose() method , is there memory leak for the Subject that is not completed?

If there is memory leak, then how can I detect in js library that webpage is reloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page is reloaded the whole JS vm is restared. There is no risk of memory leak !